# Android not using right layout according to screen size

Tags: android, layout, screen

So I have two sets of layout, one for a 7inch tablet, one for a 10 inch tablet.

```
Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK
```

shows large for the 7, xlarge for the 10 device. I created two folders, layout-large and layout-xlarge, but the 7inch device uses the x-large layouts (I even deleted the normal layout folder).

What could be my problem here?

EDIT: I also tried the new qualifiers according to http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DeclaringTabletLayouts, making the layout folder for the 10"

```
layoutw1280dp
```

which the 7" cannot possiblys have, still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Don't underestimate how many pixels these small screens can have. The Samsung Galaxy S3 has 720x1280 screen. That screen couldn't be larger than 7"

From the documentation:

```
xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp
```

Which tablet is it?

Comment: It's Samsung Galaxy Tab1(10) and a Huawei MediaPad3g(7).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry bothering you guys, obviously it was not an Android problem, but an Eclipse one, somehow the layout files within the folders got mixed up when I imported the project.